# SVG path element value in html

Tags: javascript, selenium, dom, svg, automation

I am writing automated test using selenium web driver.

The web page I am testing has a graph made by SVG. The graph has some points that indicate some statistical values and as part of my automation I need to find those values.
The points are created by svg path element.

Using firebug console I can see the values I need in DOM but can't find the same value in html.

Can anyone help me to figure out how to find in HTML the value I can see in DOM.

Comment: What does "find in HTML" mean?

Comment: The element in which I am interested has "value" property in DOM:
<value   82>

Now I need to somehow get that 82 from HTML but HTML doesn't seem to contain that information.

Comment: I think you're going to need to give us a [mcve] here.